# Add new protocol "listener" to asp.net generic host

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm not even sure how to express this question which is likely why my normal google-Fu failed me. So here goes. Visual studio has several project templates that the generic host. There is the worker service for console applications, webhost for asp.net and an template for grpc.

All those hosts somehow translate a request over a certain protocol to actions in the application. Webhost uses Http as a communications layer, grpc uses grpc. NServicesBus uses messagequeue's.

I'm trying to find examples of what is needed to implement a custom "protocol mapper" Does anyone know of any example to do this? Or basic documentation on what would need to be implemented.

Basically what is behind functions like ConfigureWebhostDefaults or UseNServiceBus for NServiceBus etc etc.. Soemthing that listens for network calls or other events and then fires up the correct function in the correct controllers to use MVC terms.

This is not the clearest question I have asked, but it does not help if one does not know how the thing you are looking for is named.

Comment: Hmm. Like a listener that accepts service bus (or another protocol) messages and converts them into HTTP requests and send them down the MVC pipeline? Check out `IServer` and its implementations (mainly Kestrel): https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions/IServer.cs,5aa0425d70e5445f,references

Comment: @abdusco More or less, but I see no need to force it down the mvc pipeline by converting it to http. The "listener" should be able to figure out what to call to handle any request. Just like NServiceBus does as an example. But that code is to large for me to easily figure out where to start.